# Error: TypeError: Object has no method 'set'

Tags: javascript, ios, parse-platform

I am using a cloud code function for my iOS app. I am calling the cloud function with this code...

```
var moment = require("moment");

Parse.Cloud.define("registerActivity", function(request, response) {
    var user = request.user;
    user.set("lastActive", new Date());
    user.save().then(function (user) {
        response.success();
    }, function (error) {
        console.log(error);
        response.error(error);
   });
});
```

and from iOS I call it like this...

```
[PFCloud callFunction:@"registerActivity" withParameters:@{}];
```

Why do I get this error?

```
Error: TypeError: Object  has no method 'set'
```

Comment: does your `request.user` object have a `set` method? or are you simply trying to do `user.lastActive = new Date()`

Comment: I don't know. I wouldn't be using this javascript at all if I didn't have to use it for cloud code. I am only half sure of everything I'm doing with JS. So Does it have a set method? It should. In iOS you just do `[[PFUser currentUser]setObject:[NSDate date] forKey:@"lastActive"];`. How do I do that same thing with JS and get no errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't necessarily pass parse objects through cloud functions and expect them to remain parse objects. A better solution would be to pass the object id, then create a pointer to a user object, and set that id to it. Then update and save:

```
var moment = require("moment");

Parse.Cloud.define("registerActivity", function(request, response) {
    var user = new Parse.User()
    user.id = request.userId;
    user.set("lastActive", new Date());
    user.save().then(function (user) {
        response.success();
    }, function (error) {
        console.log(error);
        response.error(error);
   });
});
```

Comment: Haha you are right. That is what I resorted to a week ago and it worked like a charm. So you are correct, just a little late lol. But you get a smiley face for trying!

Comment: Thanks! It's better to have an answer here after all, it can help others with the same problem.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why we cannot "expect them to remain parse objects"? I've encountered this problem a couple times now, but I cannot find any reason why this is the case, so I'm not sure what I need to watch out for.

Comment: @gyratorycircus: Several reasons. One is that on the iOS end you have an Objective-C type PFObject. If you simply pass that object as a parameter, you'll have to rely on some kind of serialization into JSON. Now that may be all fine, but on the receiving end, the JSON then has to be deserialized into a Parse Object. That too may be fine, but no such serialization / deserialization takes place by default. Note that a Parse Object is more than the attributes you see in the data browser, it also has prototype methods etc, and therefore contains function pointers.